# How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given this XML data:

```
<root>
  <item>apple</item>
  <item>orange</item>
  <item>banana</item>
</root>
```

I can use this XSLT markup:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="root/item">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

to get this result:

> apple, orange, banana,

but how do I produce a list where the last comma is not present? I assume it can be done doing something along the lines of:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="root/item">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="...">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

but what should the test expression be?

I need some way to figure out how long the list is and where I currently am in the list, or, alternatively, if I am currently processing the last element in the list (which means I don't care how long it is or what the current position is).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at the `position()`, `count()` and `last()` functions; e.g.,  `test="position() &lt; last()"`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Where's stuff like this documented anyway? The XPath spec?

Comment: Have a look at w3schools.com/xpath, they have a couple of great overviews of basic xpath syntax and capabilities.

Comment: I have this line: `<xsl:value-of select="@Courses"/>` which displays all the CSV but it doesn't look too user friendly. Is there any way to instead of comma, separate them by new line for each value?

Comment: @SiKni8 Please create a new question for that.

Answer (score 60):

This is a pretty common pattern:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This fails if any of the values you're iterating over are empty. This will result in trailing- or double-commas.

Comment: @aaronbauman I wouldn't call that failing, but rather a missing `if not empty` :)

Comment: For the 'if' I used: **<xsl:if test="following-sibling::\*" xml:space="preserve">, </xsl:if>**

Comment: This is indeed a common pattern, but it can be improved. Rather than adding a comma after every item except the last, it's better to add a comma before every item except the first. That's because testing whether an item is the first is much easier than testing whether it's the last, because it doesn't require reading ahead.

Answer (score 15):

For an XSLT 2.0 option, you can use the `separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of`.

This `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/item" separator=", "/>
```

would produce this output:

```
apple, orange, banana
```

You could also use more than just a comma for a separator. For example, this:

```
<xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="/root/item" separator="', '"/>
<xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
```

Would produce the following output:

```
'apple', 'orange', 'banana'
```

Another XSLT 2.0 option is `string-join()`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(/*/item,', ')"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
```

or (perhaps more efficient, but you'd have to test):

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[1]">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',.)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what that test is actually doing?

Comment: the something:: indicates an axis - in this case, the following-sibling axis. There are various axes - the following-sibling axis is those nodes with the same parent that follow the current node in document order. This checks for the existence of any such nodes. If there aren't any, we're the last.

Comment: That works, but "position()=last()" doesn't have to build a node-set and then test it.  The XSLT processor might not be smart enough to know that it isn't going to need to compile a list of every following node, and if it does, that makes it a (roughly) O(n^2) operation.

Comment: (Of course I meant "position() != last()".  The devil is in the details.)

Comment: I'll post an alternative, then ;-p

Comment: What would be the advantages/disadvantages of this compared to the @RobertRossney version?

Answer (score 7):

**A simple XPath 1.0 one-liner**:

**`concat(., substring(',', 2 - (position() != last())))`**

Put it into this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select=
         "concat(., substring(',', 2 - (position() != last())))"
         />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and apply it to the XML document**:

```
<root>
    <item>apple</item>
    <item>orange</item>
    <item>banana</item>
</root>
```

**to get the wanted result:**

`apple,orange,banana`

**EDIT:**

Here is a comment from Robert Rossney to this answer:

> That's pretty opaque code for a human
>   to read. It requires you to know two
>   non-obvious things about XSLT: 1) what
>   the substring function does if its
>   index is out of range and 2) that
>   logical values can be implicitly
>   converted to numerical ones.

**and here is my answer**:

*Guys, never shy from learning something new. In fact this is all Stack Overflow is about, isn't it? :)*

Comment: That's pretty opaque code for a human to read.  It requires you to know two non-obvious things about XSLT: 1) what the substring function does if its index is out of range and 2) that logical values can be implicitly converted to numerical ones.

Comment: @ Robert-Rossney Sure, part of its value is exactly in this!

Answer (score 7):

Robert gave the classis `not(position() = last())` answer. This requires you to process the whole current node list to get context size, and in large input documents this might make the conversion consume more memory. Therefore, I normally invert the test to be the first thing

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)>, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of why you wouldn't want to do that, and not coming up with a reason.

Comment: position()!=last() won't work if you want exclude some of the items in the sequence. For instance what would happen if had a list like this:
<list>
 <apple>delicious</apple>
 <banana>dole</banana>
 <orange>navel</orange>
</list>
with the template <template match="orange"/> to exclude oranges.

Comment: @BeWarned, if you can't omit oranges in the select statement, then solutions with position() will not work. However, in this questions there are no template based exlucedes, so that doesn't really apply here.

Comment: A processor might be able to optimize a `position()=last()` test to only use one-step lookahead, but the solution of putting a separator before every item except the first is definitely to be preferred because (a) it involves no lookahead at all, and (b) it avoids any reliance on smart optimization.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I got it working for me.
I tested this against your list:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:call-template name="comma-join"><xsl:with-param name="list" select="item"/></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="comma-join">
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```