# XSLT Concatenating the values with comma (,)

Tags: xslt

i need to loop through all the nodes in the xml document 
and append the values with comma ( , )
finally after the last element i should not have commma (,)

can any body help me.

thanking you,
Ramana kumar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
    <xsl:value-of select="whatever" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `position()` function returns the index of the current element in the `for-each` context, and `last()` returns the index of the last element.

The [Conditional Processing with `xsl:if`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:if) section of the XSLT documentation provides more information about this example.

Answer (score 12):

In **XSLT 2.0** (or greater) you can use the [**string-join** function](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-string-join).

```
<xsl:value-of  select="string-join(/element/whatever, ',')"/>
```

Comment: i want to know, wether XSLT 2.0 is supported in .net 3.5

Comment: .NET does not have native XSLT 2.0 support, but Saxon is an option for .NET 2.0 or later: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Saxon is slow as hell, I recommend you to stick to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @astrojuanlu:  I'd recommend that you either backup your unsubstantiated claim with a reliable citation, or delete your comment.   As it stands, it reflects more poorly on you than on Saxon.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In **XSLT 2.0** (or greater) you can use [`xsl:value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) with a separator:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/element/whatever" separator=","/>
```

> If the separator attribute is present, then the effective value of this attribute is used to separate adjacent items in the result sequence