# XML to flat file conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert the following XML to a flatfile with delimiter as "|", using XSLT.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><GeneralLedgerReport targetNamespace="http://www.portal.com/schemas/GLSync" xmlns="http://www.portal.com/schemas/GLSync" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.portal.com/schemas/GLSync brm_gl_data.xsd">
        <SourceSystemID>Germany</SourceSystemID>
        <ReportID>0.0.0.1-697031-1136</ReportID>
        <RevenueType>Unbilled earned</RevenueType>
        <BRM_GL_Segment>.</BRM_GL_Segment>
        <ReportCreatedTime>
                <Year>2013</Year>
                <Month>01</Month>
                <Day>14</Day>
                <Hours>16</Hours>
                <Minutes>2</Minutes>
                <Seconds>3</Seconds>
        </ReportCreatedTime>
        <PeriodStartTime>
                <Year>2012</Year>
                <Month>10</Month>
                <Day>15</Day>
                <Hours>0</Hours>
                <Minutes>0</Minutes>
                <Seconds>0</Seconds>
        </PeriodStartTime>
        <PeriodEndTime>
                <Year>2012</Year>
                <Month>10</Month>
                <Day>16</Day>
                <Hours>0</Hours>
                <Minutes>0</Minutes>
                <Seconds>0</Seconds>
        </PeriodEndTime>
</GeneralLedgerReport>
```

Required Output:
                                  General Ledger Report

Germany|0.0.0.1-697031-1136|Unbilled earned|2013/01/14-16:02:03|2012/10/15-00:00:00
Germany|0.0.0.1-697031-1136|Unbilled earned|2013/01/14-16:02:03|2012/10/15-00:00:00
Germany|0.0.0.1-697031-1136|Unbilled earned|2013/01/14-16:02:03|2012/10/15-00:00:00
Germany|0.0.0.1-697031-1136|Unbilled earned|2013/01/14-16:02:03|2012/10/15-00:00:00

I tried couple of things but the output comes as:

Germany0.0.0.1-697031-1136Unbilled earned20130114160203201210150

Need this urgently, please help!
Thanks!

I am new to XSLT, not sure how to get the elements separately with delimiters, I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
        xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt java">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:value-of  select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

More XML:

```
    <SourceSystemID>Germany</SourceSystemID>
    <ReportID>0.0.0.1-697031-1116</ReportID>
    <RevenueType>Unbilled earned</RevenueType>
    <BRM_GL_Segment>.</BRM_GL_Segment>
    <ReportCreatedTime>
            <Year>2013</Year>
            <Month>01</Month>
            <Day>14</Day>
            <Hours>16</Hours>
            <Minutes>1</Minutes>
            <Seconds>59</Seconds>
    </ReportCreatedTime>
    <PeriodStartTime>
            <Year>2012</Year>
            <Month>09</Month>
            <Day>25</Day>
            <Hours>0</Hours>
            <Minutes>0</Minutes>
            <Seconds>0</Seconds>
    </PeriodStartTime>
    <PeriodEndTime>
            <Year>2012</Year>
            <Month>09</Month>
            <Day>26</Day>
            <Hours>0</Hours>
            <Minutes>0</Minutes>
            <Seconds>0</Seconds>
    </PeriodEndTime>
    <SourceSystemID>Germany</SourceSystemID>
    <ReportID>0.0.0.1-697031-1136</ReportID>
    <RevenueType>Unbilled earned</RevenueType>
    <BRM_GL_Segment>.</BRM_GL_Segment>
    <ReportCreatedTime>
            <Year>2013</Year>
            <Month>01</Month>
            <Day>14</Day>
            <Hours>16</Hours>
            <Minutes>2</Minutes>
            <Seconds>3</Seconds>
    </ReportCreatedTime>
    <PeriodStartTime>
            <Year>2012</Year>
            <Month>10</Month>
            <Day>15</Day>
            <Hours>0</Hours>
            <Minutes>0</Minutes>
            <Seconds>0</Seconds>
    </PeriodStartTime>
    <PeriodEndTime>
            <Year>2012</Year>
            <Month>10</Month>
            <Day>16</Day>
            <Hours>0</Hours>
            <Minutes>0</Minutes>
            <Seconds>0</Seconds>
    </PeriodEndTime>
```

Comment: you have to declare the namespace (prefix and URI) otherwise you won't be able to select elements in the input tree. Moreover, is correct the output you want? It is just a line repeated four times??

Comment: @empo: Basically the input is a huge XML repetited the same way, that's why I need the output as the same number of lines to be repeated. I'll try to add prefix and URI.                               Is this correct? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
        xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt java">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

Comment: Please post a bit more of your input xml (edit your question do not use comments)

Comment: @empo Edited the question, please check now

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this question but use a | instead of a comma

[XSLT Concatenating the values with comma (,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998019/xslt-concatenating-the-values-with-comma)

Comment: Thanks Conrad! I'm new to XSLT and not sure how to pick each of the elements separately. I just tried the following:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> <xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/> </xsl:template> <xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>                          Can u please help in this, i tried looking for some examples but nothing concrete

Comment: Ignacio, please see the above post, I have posted the code tried

Answer (score 0):

You can get some inspiration from the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:glsync="http://www.portal.com/schemas/GLSync" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="glsync:GeneralLedgerReport">
        <xsl:value-of select="./glsync:SourceSystemID" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./glsync:ReportID" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./glsync:RevenueType" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./glsync:ReportCreatedTime" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./glsync:PeriodStartTime" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="glsync:ReportCreatedTime">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="concat(
                glsync:Year, '/', 
                glsync:Month, '/', 
                glsync:Day, '-', 
                format-number(glsync:Hours, '00'), ':', 
                format-number(glsync:Minutes, '00'), ':', 
                format-number(glsync:Seconds,  '00'))" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="glsync:PeriodStartTime">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="concat(
                glsync:Year, '/', 
                glsync:Month, '/', 
                glsync:Day, '-', 
                format-number(glsync:Hours, '00'), ':', 
                format-number(glsync:Minutes, '00'), ':', 
                format-number(glsync:Seconds,  '00'))" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some notes:

- you must use namespace in matching elements, because your XML has a `targetNamespace`;
- you could use the `concat` function also in the template matching `glsync:GeneralLedgerReport`
- note the use of the `format-number` function to get hours, minutes and seconds on two digits
- finally, your longer XML seems strange because all `GeneralLedgerReport`, `ReportCreatedTime`, `PeriodStartTime` and `PeriodEndTime` tags are on the same level; perhaps you have some tag enclosing them so that you have nested structures for every `GeneralLedgerReport`

I hope this helps.