# Combining XML records into meaningful sentence: "Dale, Harry and Lucy"

Tags: xml, xslt

Say I have this in XML

```
<people>
    <name>Dale</name>
    <name>Harry</name>
    <name>Lucy</name>
</people>
```

How would I go about transforming this into

```
Dale, Harry and Lucy
```

using just XSLT? It has to be flexible to a certain point, so that where there are more `name`s, it would still make sense.

```
Dale, Harry, Lucy, James, Andy, Shelly and Norma
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath)

Comment: Just a quick reminder -- though i know stack exchange hates offsite references  -- that there's an xslt FAQ website, easily findable by websearching that phrase,  which contains all the best tips from the first several years of the xsl mailing lisr, back when this tool was new. It's still a great resource for previous solutions, including some which achieve things we thought xslt 1.0 couldn't do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath), but not identical to it. The only thing you need to add is a second condition that determines when `and` should be inserted.

**XML Input**

```
<people>
    <name>Dale</name>
    <name>Harry</name>
    <name>Lucy</name>
    <name>John</name>
</people>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>

        <xsl:if test="$pos = last() and $pos != 1">
            <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:value-of select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="$pos != last() and $pos + 1 != last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
Dale, Harry, Lucy and John
```

---

Or, if you prefer cryptic code, but fewer lines, it can be done with a single XPath expression (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="name">    
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,
    substring(', ', 3 - ((position() != last() and position() + 1 != last()) * 2)),
    substring(' and ', 6 - ((position() = last() - 1) * 5)))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k Edited the answer. Now it works for a single `name`, too - I'd prefer your solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=last() - 1"> and </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```