# Convert repeating node to a comma delimited using XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT and I need help with my question:

I have repeating node in an XML and I would like to convert the repeating node to a comma delimited string using XSLT. and if there is an N/A in one of the repeating nodes, ignore it and fetch the other nodes

```
<Studios>
  <Studio>Hollywood</CustName>
  <Studio>Santa Monica</CustName>
  <Studio>N/A</CustName>
</Studios>
```

Expected result should be:

```
Hollywood, Santa Monica
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Duplicate/mild variation of [How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath)

Comment: I'm stuck with ignoring if its N/A.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/668850/290085) plus an enclosing test that the string value of the current `Studio` is not `"N/A"`.   You can do it.

Comment: "*I'm stuck with ignoring if its N/A.*" You should have posted the code you have that doesn't ignore N/A, so that we can fix it - instead of having to start from scratch. -- And your XML is invalid: `</CustName>` does not close `<Studio>`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm stuck with ignoring if its N/A.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Studio[not(.='N/A')]">
```