# XSLT comma separation for sublist of list

Tags: xml, xslt

How to do with XSLT from this

```
<lines>
  <data>
    a
  </data>
  <data>
    b
  </data>
  <data>
    a
  </data>
  <data>
    b
  </data>
  <data>
    c
  </data>
  <data>
    b
  </data>
  <data>
    c
  </data>
</lines>
```

this

```
<resultdata>
  b,b,b
</resultdata>
```

As far as i understand i shal use

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data">
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="data(text)='b'">
```

and

```
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
```

But how exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/data">
```

You need to do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/lines/data">
```

This is because the initial `/` represents the document node, which is the parent node of `lines`. However, it would actually be better if you were positioned on the `lines` element at the time (by being in a template that matched `lines`). Then you could just do this (because without the preceding `/` the expression is then relative to the current node).

```
<xsl:for-each select="data">
```

To check the text of the node, you need to do this:

```
<xsl:if test="text()='b'">
```

Or rather, because you have white-space, you should be doing this:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space()='b'">
```

Or better still, you add the condition to the `xsl:for-each` itself.

```
<xsl:for-each select="data[normalize-space() = 'b']">
```

Try this XSLT to start you going:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="lines">
        <resultdata>
            <xsl:for-each select="data[normalize-space() = 'b']">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </resultdata>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just a side note: The declarative nature of xslt would be honored better if instead of ``xsl:for-each``, the more idiomatic ``xsl:apply-templates`` syntax were used. The reason I say this is, that many people get used to the for-each quickly and then try to do anything with it - until they eventually find a problem where apply-templates power is needed.

Comment: That's great and works! Now i have to scale this scheme to real example (in next comment)