# XSLT comma separation for sublist of list (complex case)

Tags: xml, xslt

real xml structure

```
<GTD>
<BLOCK>
  <G44>
    <G4403>1</G4403>
    <G441>02001</G441>
    <G442>N/A</G442>
    <G443>2015-04-12</G443>
  </G44>
  <G44>
    <G4403>1</G4403>
    <G441>02015</G441>
    <G442>143561</G442>
    <G443>2015-07-28</G443>
  </G44>
  <G44>
    <G4403>1</G4403>
    <G441>03011</G441>
    <G442>SRSC-3399709-2015</G442>
    <G443>2014-12-01</G443>
  </G44>
  <G44>
    <G4403>1</G4403>
    <G441>02015</G441>
    <G442>143537</G442>
    <G443>2015-07-26</G443>
  </G44>
  <G44>
    <G4403>1</G4403>
    <G441>03012</G441>
    <G442>1</G442>
    <G443>2014-12-01</G443>
  </G44>
</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
  ...
</BLOCK>
</GTD>
```

in result XML i must have from each **G44** with **G441 = 02015** concatinated string with commas delimiter

```
<GTD>
<LINE>
  <DOCNUMBER>
    143561, 143537
  </DOCNUMBER>
</LINE>
</GTD>
```

The question connected with another one ([XSLT comma separation for sublist of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452020/xslt-comma-separation-for-sublist-of-list))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you tagged this "complex case" ;). Here's how to do this with XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <GTD><LINE><DOCNUMBER>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="GTD/BLOCK/G44[G441 = '02015']" />
    </DOCNUMBER></LINE></GTD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G44">
    <xsl:value-of select="G442" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This results in:

```
<GTD>
  <LINE>
    <DOCNUMBER>143561, 143537</DOCNUMBER>
  </LINE>
</GTD>
```

### Update, adding suggestion from comment

To give a hint as to how to expand this based on your comment on `PACKNUMBER`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <GTD><LINE>
        <DOCNUMBER>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="GTD/BLOCK/G44[G441 = '02015']" />
        </DOCNUMBER>
        <PACKNUMBER>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="GTD/BLOCK/G44[G441 = '02001']" />
        </PACKNUMBER>
    </LINE></GTD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G44[G441 = '02015']">
    <xsl:value-of select="G442" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G44[G441 = '02001']">
    <xsl:value-of select="G441" />
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="G443" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You can decide whether you want to repeat the predicate, or switch modes. But essentially, the way to do this is:

- add a new collection by adding a new apply-templates
- describe what you want with it by adding a new matching template

In case of overlap (same output to generate for another collection), you can add multiple matches in one by using `match="G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = 'xyz]">`.

Comment: This logic will work even for sever concationation? I mean for grouping several values, not only by '02015' key. For example DOCNUMBER is for '02015', PACKNUMBERS is fo '02001' and need tocollect DOCNUMBERS from G441 and DOCDATE from G443

Comment: @V.Plotnikov: obviously, if your current code must do more, you will need to adapt it. But as written, it creates the output you requested. And yes, you can add other requirements, either by adding them to the `DOCNUMBER` element, or by processing them separately by adding an extra `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: @V.Plotnikov: I have updated the answer to show how you can expand on this requirement with `PACKNUMBER`.

Comment: Thank you very mutch! Now i understand the logic!

Comment: And one more question. for one templete i need to concationate two lines. one it's DOCNUMBER, and second it's DOCDATES. In your example i can see in template two lines with value-of for both, but in upper text only DOCNUMBER without DOCDATES

Comment: @V.Plotnikov, I'm sorry, I am not aware of your full current stylesheet. Concatenation can be done with `concat`, or as I showed above by adding an extra `xsl:value-of`. You can update these to match what you need. If you have trouble, you should better ask a new question with your new specific question, as we are starting to diverge quite a bit from your original requirement and that's not very useful for future visitors.