# Merging strings in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have this XML:

```
<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

The result that I am wishing for is

```
Harry Potter, Learning XML
```

How do I make the comma appear in the output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/666602/1363

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
concat(/bookstore/book[1]/title, ', ', /bookstore/book[2]/title)
```

will return this string

```
Harry Potter, Learning XML
```

as requested.